# How to pass a variable into HTML-tags of a Material ui Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the following Material ui component:

```
<CardTitle children={child} />
```

Now I want to add some HTML code containing a variable, which will change with the state of my react component

```
...
render() {
  const child = (<p>this.state.var</p>);

  return (
    ...
    <CardTitle children={child} />
    ...
  );
}
...
```

}

**How can achieve this?**

Do I have to create another component, which I include as HTML tag?

Comment: r u getting any error when using in this way u explained in ur ques ?? because i think it will work.

Comment: It does not interpret `this.state.var`. The output would be literally `<p>this.state.var</p>`.

Comment: ok my bad I forgot two wrap the expression into curly brackets `<p>{this.state.var}</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs in version 4 `CardHeader` title field has `node` type. Hence you can use e.g.

```
<CardHeader title={<div>{addressFrom} &rarr; {addressTo}</div>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this `jsfiddle`, we can use html element inside `CardTitle`:
https://jsfiddle.net/cy167jme/